# container for binary search as well as insert and delete

Tags: c++, stl

I am looking for a `STL` container or any other data structure that can do Binary Search in `O(log n)` time and also support insert and delete in atmost `O(log n)` time. Is it possible ? `n` = no. of elements in the Container.
Note - Binary Search here means knowing the indices and accessing values based on index.

Comment: You may be looking for `std::set`

Comment: How can set implement binary search in `O(log n)` ?

Comment: `set::find` works in `log n` time. In what way does it not meet your requirements? What do you believe you need indices for?

Comment: _accessing values based on index_ ... that would be [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) which has complexity of `O(log n)` for `find`, `insert` and `erase` method overloads that take an index (aka *key*) parameter (scroll down on the reference pages to find complexity guarantees).

Comment: @zett42 Thats ok, but what if I delete in a map, the indices remain as it is, they dont change.

Comment: Yes this is how map works. I don't believe you can achieve `O(log n)` delete if you have to reassign indices. What do you need this for?

Comment: @zett42 Thanks anyways ! I was curious about this data structure and hence asked, it hit me while solving a problem. The problem is I see, random Access (for B Search via index) and O(log n) delete/insert can physically not occur simultaneously.